# How can this Rails action be refactored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can this simple `new` action be refactored?

```
def new
  @payment = Payment.new(:invoice_id => params[:invoice_id])
  if @payment.invoice.present?    
    @payment.amount = @payment.invoice.balance.abs
  end
  @title = "New payment"
end
```

It feels a bit clumsy to me.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Refactoring is sort of a subjective topic so it's not really a good fit for Stack Overflow. Two solutions would be to use model callbacks or override the Payment#amount method with this logic. Maybe try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is `params` a method? If not, your code will not run.

Comment: @sawa this is probably in a controller where params is a hash of values

Comment: Move all business logic into the model. See the answer by dquimper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify your controller, you should move the business logic to your model.

Here's three suggestion:

If invoice_id will not change over the live of your Payment instance, and you don't need caching:

```
  def amount
    invoice.balance.abs
  end
```

If invoice_id will not change over the live of your Payment instance, but you use the amount value multiple times in your controller/view. (use caching):

```
  def amount
    @_amount ||= invoice.balance.abs
  end
```

If invoice_id may change over the live of your Payment instance, and you need caching:

```
  def amount
    @_amount ||= {}
    @_amount[invoice_id] ||= invoice.balance.abs
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still trying to decide which one is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not run unless you have a method called `params`, but assuming you have that:

```
def new
  @payment = Payment.new(:invoice_id => params[:invoice_id])
  .tap{|pay| pay.invoice.tap{|inv| pay.amount = inv.balance.abs if inv.present?}}
  @title = "New payment"
end
```

Comment: That `tap` method is new to me but thanks!